# After success authentication using keycloak rest controller method not getting invoked instead serving /static/index.html file

Tags: spring-boot, rest, keycloak, spring-rest, static-html

Using keycloak and spring boot, after successful authentication GET request is forwarded to /static/index.html file instead of the RestController method below. System.out.println in the below method also not getting executed.
This issue happened after migrating from jdk1.8 to jdk 21 and after upgrading spring boot to 3.1.4
how to fix this issue.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(("/api/user"))
@Slf4j
public class UserController {

   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;

   @GetMapping("me")
   public ResponseEntity<?> me(Principal principal) {
        System.out.println("***************************************************************");
       if (principal == null) {
           return ControllerUtil.getUnauthorizedResponse();
       }
       return userService.getUserDetails(new IAppsUser(principal));
   }
}
```

I am expecting it should print the println statement in the method me(Principal principal)
and execute the code properly

Comment: you  probably ended up changing your SecurityConfig and forgot to change the redirect uri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading to latest jdk 21 and spring boot 3.1.4 I found that it is not scanning the base package as before. So I added the package in the main class and the issue got resolved